# How to change multiple directories' name by computation on the numbers in the names?

Tags: shell

I have some directories. Their names are as follows,

```
s1_tw
s2_tw
s3_tw
s4_tw
```

How to change their names by add a fixed integer to the number following "s"? How can I change the directories' name to

```
s22_tw
s23_tw
s24_tw
s25_tw
```

by changing `s1` to `s22`  (1 + 21 = 22),  `s2` to `s23`, etc?  (Here adding 21 is expected)

I tried with

```
for f in s*_tw
do 
    for i in `seq 1 1 4`
    do 
        mv -i "${f//s${i}/s(${i}+21)}"
    done
done
```

But I know it is not correct, because I can not perform addition operation in this command. Could you please give some suggestions?

Comment: `for f in s*_tw; do for i in seq 1 1 40` but why are you looping over numbers from 1 to 40?

Comment: I should use `for i in  \`seq 1 1 4\` `. It is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will rename your directories:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "s?_tw" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' dir
do
    digit=$(echo "$dir" | sed 's#./s\([0-9]\)_tw#\1#')
    echo "DIGIT=$digit"

    (( newdigit = digit + 21 ))
    echo "NEWDIGIT=$newdigit"

    mv "$dir" "s${newdigit}_tw"
done
```

- The `find -print0` with `while` and `read` comes from https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001.